# System is not defined in browser-side of compiled javascript

Tags: typescript, lit

My tsconfig.json is as :

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "useDefineForClassFields": false,
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "module": "system",
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "removeComments": true,
      "preserveConstEnums": true,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "lib": ["es2015", "dom"]
    }
}
```

`tsc` runs successfully.

But when I load http://localhost:8005 in the browser `Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined`

My example ts code is as follows :

```
import {LitElement, html} from 'lit';
import {customElement, property} from 'lit/decorators.js';

@customElement('my-element')
export class MyElement extends LitElement {
  @property()
  version = 'STARTING';

  render() {
    return html`
    <p>Welcome to the Lit tutorial!</p>
    <p>This is the ${this.version} code.</p>
    `;
  }
}
```